# No library found for Django + React integrating sign in with Google 2022 (Google Identity Services)

Tags: reactjs, django, oauth-2.0, django-allauth, sign-in-with-google

For React there is a library - [React OAuth2 | Google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google)

For Django [AllAuth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) library existed

But after new update in **Sign in with Google 2022** (Google Identity Services) AllAuth is not been updated. There is no other libraries or easier documentation?

So please suggest me some library for Django

Comment: Did you ever find a solution/fitting library?

Comment: No I moved to OTP based authentication. If you really need email authentication check [Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).Beacuse Google Identity Services 2022 authentication library for Django is still unavailable.

Comment: Mh, damn. Thanks for getting back to me :) We evaluated this further and decided to customize the existing django-allauth provider to support the new functionalities. As a newcomer to SSO I felt really stupid along the way, though, and struggled to implement this properly. The new (rather conflicting) naming of the Google docs did also not help.